# How to write this xml in java code

Tags: java, android, xml

Android XML:

```
<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/hello"
android:layout_height="28dp" android:layout_width="180dp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/signinemailtxt"
android:paddingLeft="50dp"
android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
android:background="#ffffff" 

/>
```

Java:

```
layout=  new  RelativeLayout(this);
layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
TextView Txt=new TextView(this);
Txt.setText("Name");
```

How to get layout_marginTop,layout_toRightOf options in java code

Answer (score 1):

```
  RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setText("A");

TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
tv2.setText("B");
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, tv1.getId());

layout.addView(tv1);        
layout.addView(tv2, lp);
```

Comment: if i want this textview to be there in particlar position..
x=34px and y=30px

Comment: if u want x=34 and y = 30 px. just change this line : RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        34, 30);

Comment: i want textview to be in 34 ,30 not the entire layout

Answer (score 1):

For layout_margin :

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(context, attrs);
params.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 5); //setMargins (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)

Txt.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: what i have put here context, attrs

Comment: Context context = getApplicationContext(); // you can use YourClass.this too

Comment: XmlPullParser parser = res.getXml(R.layout.your-layout);
AttributeSet attributes = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);

Comment: where Resources res = getResources();

Comment: XmlPullParser parser = res.getXml(R.layout.main);
        AttributeSet attributes = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(context,attributes); is an error

Answer (score -1):

Don't declare new instances of layout and text view, but get the ones you created in the xml:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.LayoutId);
TextView Txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewId);
```

Now you can edit the layout and textview you are seeing on the screen.